# Do I need to create a separate class in my models.py when using the django.contrib.auth.models import user?

Tags: python, django

The import statement import the needed parts. but is the "user" class already made when you put that into your installed apps? or do you still need to clarify in models.py in order to make the table in the db? or can someone expand on how to use django users and sessions? I'm looking over the django docs right now and they all just go over how to use the thing once. they never put the code in a syntax where users are going to be the ones using the code through a browser and not you through a python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All installed apps can contribute to the database schema. `django.contrib.auth.models` contributes, among others, the `auth_user` table behind the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, therefore you do not have to worry about recreating it unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things going on here. As you're aware, Django comes with a number of "contrib" packages that can be used in your app. You "activate" these by putting them into your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

When you run `python manage.py syncdb`, Django parse the models.py files of every app in `INSTALLED_APPS` and creates the associated tables in your database. So, once you have added `django.contrib.auth` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and ran `syncdb`, the tables for `User` and `Group` are there and ready to be used.

Now, if you want to use these models in your other apps, you can import them, as you mention, with something like `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. You can then do something like create a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` or `ManyToManyField` on one of your models to the `User` model. When you do this, no tables are created (with the exception of `ManyToManyField`; more on that in a bit). The same table is always used for `User`, just as for any of your own models that you might create relationships between.

`ManyToManyField`s are slightly different in that an intermediary table is created (often called a "join table") that links both sides of the relationship together. However, this is purely for the purposes of that one particular relationship -- nothing about the actual `User` table is different or changed in any way.

The point is that one table is created for `User` and this same table is used to store all `User`s no matter what context they were created in. You can import `User` into any and all of your apps, create as many and as varied relationships as you like and nothing really changes as far as `User` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If the table name or something else does not fit in your needs you can always just extend the User model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Employee(User):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Any class extending `Model` class in `models.py` contributes to database schema. That means, django search your (and also django core) `model.py` files and looks for any class that extends `Model` like:

```
some models.py

class SomeModel(Model):
    ...
    ...

class Otherthing(Model):
    ...
```

that is also applies for django core code files. Since all Database tables named using application label and model name, database ables created by django also have that...

For example,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

If you track file hierarchy `django -> contrib -> auth` and open `models.py` file, you will see related model. Ther are also other Model classes in here, like `Permission` and `Group` models.

Since these models are under `auth` application, database tables are `auth_user`, `auth_perission` and `auth_group`

When you run `manage.py syncdb` command for the first time, django will create these tables...